# Socket connection problem: meet [socket.gaierror] when using socket.connect

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, macos-mojave

I'm learning python socket. I tried to connect to a web, but it showed connection error.

I tried to use telnet to connect to the server and it works fine. I also tried another computer and it also works. I'm using MAC OS Mojave, so I don't know what's wrong with the computer. Could anyone give some suggestions?

The code is like this:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

The error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket1.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

It expected to give the metadata and the data in the website.

Thanks very much in advance!!!!

Comment: The posted code works fine on my Mac (also with Mojave), so I think the program is okay; perhaps something is misconfigured on that Mac?  (Maybe try changing the program to use the server's IP address instead of its hostname, and see if that makes any difference)

Comment: I figured out it's Internet problem, it seems like it block me using python to make request. I changed an environment it works fine. Thank you!!!! :D

Comment: @MENGDIZHANG I am experiencing the same problem, can you please update the answer with your fix? Which environment did you change? Thanks.